How to read/inspect variables of a binary at runtime?
Let's say we compile a C program (with debugging symbols) into a binary and run it. We now want to know the state of the variables inside of the process while it is running.
The most straight forward way would be to just print the variables to stdout and read them from the log. This is what I do now, but since I'm trying to monitor variables in tracking loops this has the following disadvantages:

Lots of clutter in stdout, other information obfuscated
Degraded performace due to printf delays (= tracking loops influenced!)
Inspecting different variables requires changing the code and recompiling

I was wondering if there would be a way to access the variables from outside. Without printing. Surely, we could dig in the process' memory, but this would be anything but a trivial task.
At the same time, we know it is possible to get to the variables, because gdb can do it. If gdb can access them, I think we should also be able to get to them with some unix commands? Or am I mistaken here?

If the variables are at a fixed position (global or static), once you know the addresses, you could just read /proc/<pid>/mem directly.

I've done (2) but I use an in memory "event" ring queue to store events (without perturbing the real timing) as the printf is deferred until the queue is dumped for a post-mortem trace. See my answer: How to synchronize multiple processes in C? and look at the evt* stuff. This is similar to what a H/W logic analyzer does (or Sun's dtrace). I've used it in commercial R/T programs with great success. The event queue code is so fast that it can usually be enabled in production code.


If gdb can access them, I think we should also be able to get to them with some unix commands?

Sure: there are other UNIX commands which can access the variables. For example, lldb can also do it.
Your actual question is probably: "can we do that without a full debugger?".
The answer to that is: not really. In order to access arbitrary variables in another process at runtime, you pretty much need to implement a debugger.

However, running with a full debugger attached often induces unacceptable overhead.
The usual solution to that is to use some kind of tracing framework -- you put a bit of code into your program, and then enable individual trace points as-needed and examine the collected trace offline.
Use your preferred search engine to find such tracing frameworks.

Indeed. The overhead of a debugger would be too much. Ideally we want to avoid it. I will look into the tracing frameworks. Inserting some code is not an issue per sé.
